# Can't get TeamCity to use C# 7.1 - but works manually using msbuild

Tags: configuration, msbuild, teamcity

I have TeamCity 2019.1.5 with most recent Visual Studio Tool 2017 installed:
[image]

I have a project which uses C# 7.1 features, and it compiles locally just fine in VS 2017, and I made sure it has `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` in CSPROJ file. But when I run it from TeamCity (agent is on the same server) with the following build step:
[image]

it fails with the following error in the logs:

```
[Csc] Services\MappingService.cs(1942, 40): error CS8107: Feature 'default literal' is not available in C# 7.0. Please use language version 7.1 or greater.
```

If I start VS2017 command prompt on the server and go to the project's folder and run `msbuild tt.csproj /target:Rebuild` it works fine: compiles and I do not get any errors. Needless to say, if I remove C# 7.1-specific code, everything works in the current configuration.

I installed Visual Studio Tool 2019 and with MSBuild 16 it works without any problems as well. But I prefer to use 2017 tools so both server and dev environments are the same. What can cause this issue?

Comment: Worth checking if any of your referenced NuGet packages require a lower version of MSBuild. Also, as a test, see if you can build the .sln by changing the build file path.

Comment: Also worth checking the ToolsVersion attribute in the .csproj file - things changed around how MSBuild is located in VS2017

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and fixed it by fixing the solution configuration in the build step configuration.   It needs to be set to either "Debug" or "Release".  Mine was set to a parameter, which resolved to something other than one of those values.

[image]